# Не выводит сообщение

Tags: python, sqlite, discord.py

Не выводит сообщение, так-же нельзя трогать fetchone()[0]. Надо для того если нету варнов писало 0, если убрать будет всегда писать None, даже при добавлении варнов. Делал на БД SQLite

```
@client.command(aliases = ['warning', 'warn'])
async def __warn(ctx,member: discord.Member = None):
    if member is None:
        await ctx.send (embed = discord.Embed(
            description = f"""Количество предупреждений **{ctx.author}**: **{cursor.execute('SELECT warn FROM users WHERE id = {}'.format(ctx.author.id)).fetchone()[0]} :rage:**"""
        ))
    else:
        await ctx.send (embed = discord.Embed(
            description = f"""Количество предупреждений **{member}**: **{cursor.execute('SELECT warn FROM users WHERE id = {}'.format(member.id)).fetchone()[0]} :rage:**"""
        ))
```

Answer (score 1):

> fetchone()[0]. Надо для того если нету варнов писало 0, если убрать будет всегда писать None

А если оставить, то будет TypeError  с сообщением `'NoneType' object is not subscriptable`. Тебе нужно проверить свой sql запрос.

Ну и `или` реализовать можно так

```
@client.command(aliases = ['warning', 'warn'])
async def __warn(ctx,member: discord.Member = None):
    if member is None:
        await ctx.send (embed = discord.Embed(
            description = f"""Количество предупреждений **{ctx.author}**: **{cursor.execute('SELECT warn FROM users WHERE id = {}'.format(ctx.author.id)).fetchone() or 0} :rage:**"""
        ))
    else:
        await ctx.send (embed = discord.Embed(
            description = f"""Количество предупреждений **{member}**: **{cursor.execute('SELECT warn FROM users WHERE id = {}'.format(member.id)).fetchone() or 0} :rage:**"""
        ))
```